# Finite additivity axiom

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am studying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for homology and came across someone claiming that finite additivity follows from the other axioms, hence the additivity axiom is only needed for infinite coproducts.

**My Attempt:** Consider the long exact sequence associated with $(X \amalg Y, X)$

$$
\cdots \rightarrow H_i(X) \rightarrow H_i(X \amalg Y) \rightarrow H_i(X \amalg Y, X) \rightarrow H_{i-1}(X) \rightarrow \cdots
$$

By the universal property of the coproduct there exist a unique map $r: X \amalg Y \rightarrow X$ such that composing with the inclusion yields the identity on $X$, i.e. $r \circ \iota_X = id_X$. By functoriality of the homology functor this implies that $\iota_X$ is a split monomorphism, in particular an injective map for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence we obtain short exact sequences

$$
0 \rightarrow H_i(X) \rightarrow H_i(X \amalg Y) \rightarrow H_i(X \amalg Y, X)  \rightarrow 0
$$

Now since $X$ is closed in itself it can be excised, then by the excision axiom $H_i(X \amalg Y, X) \cong H_i(Y, \emptyset) \cong H_i(Y)$. Lastly $\iota_X$ gives a splitting of the short exact sequence, thus we can conclude

$$H_i(X \amalg Y) \cong H_i(X) \oplus H_i(Y) \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Why does it not follow from induction that the homology of an infinite coproduct is isomorphic to the infinite direct sum? I am sure that the additivity axiom is needed for infinite coproducts, I am just missing somthing. Could someone help me out:)

Comment: What would your induction step look like for an infinite index set? I think if you try to write down an argument you should quickly see why it doesn't work.

Comment: @VincentBoelens It would be the same argument, I guess. Assume we have an isomorphism $H_i(\coprod_{n = 0}^k X_n) \cong \bigoplus_{n=0}^{k} H_i(X_n)$, then applying my previous argument would yield $H_i(\coprod_{n = 0}^{k+1} X_n) \cong H_i(X_{k+1}) \oplus H_i(\coprod_{n=0}^{k} X_n) \cong \bigoplus_{n=0}^{k+1} H_i(X_n)$. Hence it would hold for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This should be wrong, thats why I am asking the question.

Comment: It does hold for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. A natural number, however, is finite, not infinite.

Comment: @Thorgott of course... thanks for pointing it out